# Vue.js - 2 way binding not working. Data is not updating when changed in a component

Tags: vue.js

I have a 'Builder' component and I am passing a variable named 'formula' to that component, but the changes made in this variable in 'Builder' component do not get updated in current component.

```
<builder :formula="formula"
    :columns="columns"
    :result_type="result_type">
</builder>
```

When I submit form the value for the 'formula' variable is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<builder :formula.sync="formula"
    :columns="columns"
    :result_type="result_type">
</builder>
```

Comment: It is deprecated in VueJS 2: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed

Answer (score 0):

As in VueJS 2 `.sync` - 2 way binding has been deprecated, you have to handle it differently. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed

You have to emit events like `this.$emit('formulaChange', formula)` etc. and listen to them in parent component with `@formulaChange=yourHandler(formula)`